# Complex Function Theory - The Algebra and Geometry of Complex Numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have problems with solving the following exercise.

**4.11** Show that $\sqrt{zw} = \sqrt {z} \sqrt{w}$ need not be true for arbitrary complex numbers $z$ and $w$. Confirm that this formula is valid, however, if either $z$ or $w$ is a non-negative real number.

The exercise is found in the book "Bruce P. Palka - An Introduction to Complex Function Theory".

Somebody help me please.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  How do you define $\sqrt z$ for arbitrary complex numbers $z$?  There are two solutions to $u^2=z$ when $|z|>0$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner hopefully the author picked a convention in OP's book, but the answer is the same whether we choose a branch or multivalued convention for square root.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You don't need to venture from the real numbers to get a counterexample. What happens if there is a minus sign under the square root?

Comment: That is precisely my difficulty.